# ruamel.yaml weird behavior with datetime like values

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

check.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import json

from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml = YAML(pure=True)
yaml.sort_base_mapping_type_on_output = None
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)


def yamlCheck(file: os.PathLike):
    with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as yr:
        data = yaml.load(yr)

    print(data)

    check = json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    print(check)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    yamlCheck('test.yaml')
```

test1.yaml, with error.

```
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 2000-12-26
```

test2.yaml, runs ok

```
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 111-12-26
```

test2.yaml, runs ok

```
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 2000-12-26111
```

`runs ok` means the code runs without error, json.dumps load the OrderedDict data well.

with the output of `print(data)` I think ruamel.yaml has parse that xxxx-xx-xx formatted data as datetime and construct a datetime object with it, which causes the json.dumps function's error.

So what is the standard of the ruamel.yaml to decide to parse the value as datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you consider weird behaviour, `ruamel.yaml` uses a regular
expression to implicitly tag a scalar as a timestamp as defined in `resolver.py`.
That regex is adapted from the regular expression in
[Timestamp Language Independent Type for YAML](https://yaml.org/type/timestamp.html).

The regex assumes 4 digits for the year and a maximum of two for the month and date. A valid `datetime.date`
or `datetime.datetime` (e.g. no month 2000-12-44 matches the regex, but is not a valid date)
is only checked pretty late in the compositing phase, and when it fails the scalar is assumed to be a string.

So it is normal that `2000-12-26` loads as a `date`, and that both `111-12-26` and `2000-12-26111` load
as strings.

Since `json.dumps()` doesn't support dumping `datetime.date` instances, you'll have
to explicitly convert the types to strings by specifying `default=str`, to prevent the error that you are getting.

What is weird, in my opinion, is that you assume `json.dumps()` loads something
("json.dumps load the OrderedDict data well").
That routine doesn't load, it dumps, as the name implies, and that it can
dump `OrderedDict` is because that is a subclass of `dict`

It is also inefficiently to
`print()` the result of `json.dumps()` instead
of directly dumping to `sys.stdout`.

```
import sys
import json
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_strs = [
"""\
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 2000-12-26
""",
"""\
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 111-12-26
""",
"""\
a:
  - b: 2
  - 123
  - 2000-12-26111
"""
]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
for yaml_str in yaml_strs:
    data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
    print(type(data['a'][2]))
    try:
        json.dump(data, sys.stdout, default=str)
        print() # since json.dump doesn't write a final newline
    except TypeError as e:
        print(e)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'datetime.date'>
{"a": [{"b": 2}, 123, "2000-12-26"]}
<class 'str'>
{"a": [{"b": 2}, 123, "111-12-26"]}
<class 'str'>
{"a": [{"b": 2}, 123, "2000-12-26111"]}
```